# Unable to read data from Server in Java

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I'm trying to read and write the data to the server using java program. I'm writing the data using console. I can successfully write the data to the server, but the problem comes when I try to read the data sent by the server.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;


public class EMSSocketConnection {



    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        createSocket();
    }

    private static void sendMessage(DataOutputStream out) throws Exception
    {
        try 
        {

            BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String userOutput;
            while ((userOutput = stdIn.readLine()) != null)
            {
                out.writeBytes(userOutput);
                out.write('\n');
            }
            out.flush();

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.getStackTrace());

        }
        finally
        {
            out.close();
        }
    }


    private static void readResponse(DataInputStream in) throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            in.readFully(data);
            System.out.println(data);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

        }
        finally
        {
            in.close();
        }
    }

    private static void createSocket()
    {

        try
        {
            int port = 2345;
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("192.100.100.129");
            final Socket client = new Socket(address, port);
            final DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            final DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());

            System.out.println("Successfully Connected");



            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    synchronized(client)
                    {
                        try {
                            while(true)
                            {
                            sendMessage(out);
                            readResponse(in);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.start();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.getStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Could anyone please tell me how can I successfully read the data from server?

Comment: What's the problem?  Have you got specific error messages and/or stack traces?

Comment: I've not got any error message. I can't print the sending data from server to the console.

Comment: So the server is sending 1024 bytes?  What kind of data is it? Strings, numbers?

Comment: Server is actually sending strings of not any specific size.

Comment: How is the server terminating the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your server writing 1024 bytes to its output?  If not, your code

```
byte[] data = new byte[1024];
in.readFully(data);
```

will block and wait indefinitely.

A far better idiom would be to do this:

```
byte [] data = new byte[in.available()];
in.readFully(data);
```

You cannot just read willy-nilly from streams and assume that you'll get your expected data.  Streams suffer from IO delays and buffering, and you need to be aware of this, especially when dealing with network IO.

Comment: It is not writing 1024 bytes. I earlier tried to read data using code: System.out.println(in.readUTF()), but I was unsuccessful.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I can't still read data from the Server. When I only try to run "readRespone" method I'm getting "stream closed" exception. Could you please tell me why?

Comment: Your server is clearly closing its output stream before your client is able to read the data.  Your server needs to stay alive long enough for the client to read.  The crudest way to do this would be to add a Thread.sleep() call after your server outputs its response.

Comment: Ok, now I can only read the data from the server when I comment "sendMessage" method. Do you know why?

Comment: That's not a 'far better idiom' at all. `available()` returns zero in many situations such as SSL. A far better idiom is to use a fixed size buffer, call `read()`, and save the return value, which tells you how much data was actually read; it also tells you whether you have read to EOS. There are very few valid uses of `available()` and this isn't one of them. And a fixed size buffer doesn't need to be allocated per read call, saving lots of garbage.

Comment: @EJP - fair enough on the behaviour of available(), but then what is the correct way to perform non-blocking reads on a network socket that is not guaranteed to have data on the remote side? I've personally always used available and have not yet run into issues with it, which is why I suggested it to OP.

Comment: There isn't one, by definition. That's why NIO exists.